# IIS Random bad requests - Hostname

Tags: c#, php, .net, iis, dns

I am calling upon a simple iis,php,json api using C#. I am calling upon it by IP, and manually passing the host header, as follows

```
var webhost = "api.srv.com";
var webhostip = <get ip from my own dns cache>;
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add( "Host", webhost );
response = client.DownlodData("https://" + webhostip + "/etcetc.php");
```

I am using a more reliable dns cache I've built into the application. I want to not be at the mercy of bad DNS servers/config.

This works. 99 percent of the time (the request runs very frequently). Randomly though, I will get 400 bad request. logfiles\HTTPERR shows a reason of "- Hostname -"

client.DownloadData using standard a fqdn URL and no custom header works reliably( except for when DNS fails)

To compare the two types of request, I point the client at /phpinfo.php

There is no differences.

How could this approach work 99 percent of the time but randomly fails?

Edit: The 'DNS cache' is always return IP, I am sure of that.

**Update**: I improved logging, heres the response and request data at the time

Reuqest: `https://1.2.3.4/apidir/script.php?p1=xxxx&p2=xx%20xxx`

Header: `'Host': 'api.srv.com:445'`

Response, extratced from the `WebException.Response.GetResponseStream`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

This request is running every minute, and only fails occaisionally!

The request time taken is often 60 - 90 seconds. The timeout on the WebClient is 100s. I do get timeouts when using the normal fqdn approach, however they never present as 400.

**Update**: I enabled loggin to catch a full trace at the time the issue occurs.

After a couple of these (due to my country's wonderful internet):

```
System.Net Error: 0 : [2776] Exception in HttpWebRequest#50710248::GetResponse - Unable to connect to the remote server.
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(Boolean async, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
```

I get the connection pool trying to re-establish connection (as evident by `Keep-Alive`), but it is failing to use my specified headers.

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [2776] ConnectStream#5673090 - Sending headers

Host: 1.2.3.4:445
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I'm suspecting a .Net WebClient bug.

Comment: Random errors are pure evil :)

Comment: You are telling us to not question or ask about your custom dns cache... How are we supposed to help you? Include the code.

Comment: Yeah look the IP is always getting returned I am sure of that. I just meant facetiously - obviously the DNS should be fixed but it's not an option and I want my app to not be at the mercey of bad networks

Comment: could potentialy be an issue - that doesn't reveal it's self for whatever reason when normal fqdn url is used - with a space existing in one of the query params. I've fixed that, replaced with %20, i'll see how it goes over the weekend

Comment: Ok. No idea. Wireshark shows the requests going to the server are identical. I suspect it a timeout or Timer_MinBytesPerSecond, presenting as a 400, but why it behaves differently to normal fqdn url requests is beyond me.

Comment: Sorry. I've worked it out (See answer). It's always something simple ay. I should have posted full code.

Comment: Does anyone know what the WebExceptionStatus enum value is for this particular error from IIS?

Comment: @JoeyEng it is ProtocolError, but you then need to check the status code. var WE = (WebException)E;var httpResponse = ((HttpWebResponse)WE.Response); (int)httpResponse.StatusCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to give credit to the fact that I am actually calling DownloadData 4 retry times in the case of minor comms failures(ConnectFailure, Timeout etc).

`client.Headers` gets consumed and must be re-added.

I hope this post helps someone in the future.